# play-reactivemongo dealing with Indexes

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, play-reactivemongo

I've found that in order to create an index in a collection I should use the indexesManager:

```
collection.indexesManager.ensure(...)
```

I would like to know which is the right place for this function call.

I put this call in the function of the Controller that performs the insertion of documents in the collection, and it works.
But I guess that it is not necessary to call this function on each insertion.

Is there a way to make this call only once when the DB is initialized?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `reactivemongo 2.11`, you should be able to get the current database instance like this :

`val db = current.injector.instanceOf[ReactiveMongoApi].database`

Please note that this line will give you back a `Future[DefaultDB]`. Then, you can do what you want by simply mapping on this Future :

`db.map(_.collection("myCollection")))`